# Mail Merge VBA - Access 2016 (Runtime Error 287)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Our company has recently undergone a big upgrade from office 2010 to 2016, and now we are having an issue with one of our VBA macros, shown below.

```
Function MergeIt()
Dim objWord As Word.Document
Dim SaveAsName As String
Dim Year As String
Dim DANo As String
Dim Revision As String
Dim strSource As String

Set objWord = GetObject("G:\Dev_&_Tech_Serv\Development\DAAssessTool\MailMerge1.dot", "Word.Document")
' Make Word visible.
objWord.Application.Visible = True
'Set the mail merge data source as the DAApproval Database.
objWord.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:="G:\Dev_&_Tech_Serv\Development\DAAssessTool" & "\DARevD.mdb", LinkToSource:=True, Connection:="QUERY qry_Mailmerge", SQLStatement:="Select * from [DAConCheckID]"
' Execute the mail merge.
objWord.MailMerge.Execute
' Close the original form document
objWord.Saved = True
objWord.Close (False)
End Function
```

The error is throwing at the first Set line - throwing a Runtime error 287 "Application defined or object defined error". I'm making the assumption that the previous developer is incorrectly defining the Word document, but I cant find anything online that shows a different method of defining, or how to fix this error.

I now turn to the vast knowledge of the Stack community for some inspiration on what is going wrong, and how to remedy it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice will be to convert these old .dot files to the newer .dotx format.

If this isn't feasible, try unblocking these old formats in Word Options / Trust Center / File Block Settings

see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/word-2016-cannot-open-documents-with-doc/bf12fa10-4e28-4a6b-99b2-d42c1aa8cb4b/

You may also need to set `G:` as trusted location (I assume that's a network drive).